# Private file hosting with S3: Restrict bucket/folder visibility

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ftp

I've built a very simple S3 solution for a friend who is running an archival project. He has participants who are not very good with technology, and we are trying to give each participant their own private drive. We found filestash.app which works really well as a very simple client for our participants.

But I ran into an unexpected problem. AWS does not provide any way for us to limit WHICH folders or buckets each user can see. Because our participants struggle with technology, this could be confusing for them. Our project does not have a lot of funding to draw upon, so S3 pricing is really ideal for us, but we need some way to show each user only the directory which contains his or her files. Is there any way to accomplish this at a different level? For example, is there another client we could use which lets us control what path the user is first taken to after they login? Or is this possible to accomplish using API Gateway?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/). It is multi-platform, easy to use with Drag & Drop and you can create a **bookmark** that points to a particular directory.

To limit users to a specific path within an Amazon S3 bucket, you can use this IAM User policy that is taken from [IAM policy elements: Variables and tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html):

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${aws:username}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:username}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm familiar with Cyberduck. Won't the permission / restriction be a problem at login, because it would default to the root directory?

Comment: Login would be fine, but it won't return a list of objects at the root level. You can show them how to create a bookmark that contains a path to their directory, and would take them straight there. I'd recommend playing with Cyberduck while under similar access restrictions to see the best way to ask them to configure their connection.